# Fixed point of $\cos(\sin(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I can show that $\cos(\sin(x))$ is a contraction on $\mathbb{R}$ and hence by the Contraction Mapping Theorem it will have a unique fixed point. But what is the process for finding this fixed point? This is in the context of metric spaces, I know in numerical analysis it can be done trivially with fixed point iteration. Is there a method of finding it analytically?

Comment: Probably not. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: The number $0.76816915673679597746208623955865641813208731218273718569186715\ldots$ does not ring a bell, at least, and it seems that we need a new Plouffe's inverter.

Comment: The Inverse Symbolic Calculator at http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc returns a blue square with a white question mark inside it. I don't know what that means.

Comment: @Gerry, I believe it means you are pregnant. Or possibly someone you know.

Comment: An exact form can be done by slightly modifying [this series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4569215/is-the-number-satisfying-eta-sin-cos-eta-transcendental/4714026#4714026). If this answer is wanted, then it can be posted.

Answer (score 6):

The [Jacobi-Anger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) expansion gives an expression for your formula as:

$\cos(\sin(x)) = J_0(1)+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{2n}(1) \cos(2nx)$.

Since the "harmonics" in the sum [rapidly damp to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220284/does-sint-have-the-same-frequency-as-sin-sint/), to second order the equation for the fixed point can be represented as:

$x= J_0(1) + 2[J_2(1)(\cos(2x)) + J_4(1)(\cos(4x))]$.

Using Wolfram Alpha to solve this I get $x\approx 0.76868..$

Answer (score 4):

First off, it is clear that the fixed point $x$ will lie in $[0,1]$ 
$\cos{(\sin{(x)})}=x$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$\cos^{-1}(x) = \sin{(x)}$ 
Let $F(m) = \sin{(m)} -\cos^{-1}{(m)}$ $\Rightarrow$ 
$F'(m) = \cos{(m)} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-m^{2}}}$ 
 
Then you can also find the fixed point using Newton's method. 
With $x_0$ = 0 
$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{F(m)}{F'(m)}$ 
Using MATLAB we find with $x_0:=0$ 
 
$x_{4}$ = $0.768169156736796$ 
 
which is correct to 15 decimal places. 
As far as solving analytically, I do not believe there is a way. 
Newton's method proves to be superior to functional iteration in this case, because we observe faster convergence. 
With $x_0 = 0$, 
$x_{n+1}$ = $f(x_n)$ 
$x_{40} \approx  0.768169156736780$ which is not nearly as accurate of an approximation.