# Taking repeated sin then cos

Tags: trigonometry, convergence-divergence

When you keep taking alternating sin and cos of any number as follows:

> $$\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos...(N))))...)$$

it seems to converge at about 0.69. Is there any way to find the exact value it converges at?

Comment: It will be the solution to $x=\sin(\cos(x))$. Wolfram alpha has several digits:http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28cos%28x%29%29-x%3D0&x=-925&y=-72

Comment: Don't know anything cool about it, though.

Comment: @BrianRushton. Could you explain for me how you arrived to this simple and smart reformulation of this equation ? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed point of $\cos(\sin(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246647/fixed-point-of-cos-sinx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact value may not have a nice closed form. If you take $x^*$ to be the point that this converges to, then we have
\begin{equation}
\sin(\cos(x^*)) = x^*
\end{equation}
which naturally gives us
\begin{equation}
\cos(x^*) = \arcsin(x^*).
\end{equation}
Looking at their intersection using Wolfram Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29+%3D+arcsin%28x%29) gives us the numerical approximation $x^* = 0.694819690730788...$ and I don't happen to recognize this as any familiar fraction of $\pi$ or some such expression at the moment.

Comment: Using Newton's method on $f(x)=\sin(\cos(x))-x$, starting with $x_0=0$, it converges very rapidly. $x_1=\sin(1)\approx 0.8415$, $x_2\approx 0.7007$, $x_3\approx 0.6948$.

Answer (score 2):

If taking sin and cos repeatedly has a limit, call it x. Then $\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos...)))=x$, and so, taking sin and cos of both sides,
$\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(\cos...)))))=\sin(\cos(x))$. Since the wo left sides. The quations are equal, so are the right sides.

This can be made rigorous if neccessary.